# RealTek RTL8188CE WiFi adapter doesn't connect reliably

Tags: 11.10, wireless, realtek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.10 x64 - RTL8188CE - Intermittent/Slow Internet Connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205575/12-10-x64-rtl8188ce-intermittent-slow-internet-connection)

I recently bought a new system76 laptop which came pre-installed with Ubuntu 11.10. I've been having trouble with my wireless connectivity. It seems that my connection with my wireless network keeps going in and out. It is not my network--I have seen the same problem on multiple WiFi networks and at different distances and reported link qualities.

OS version: Ubuntu 11.10 oneiric
kernel version: 3.0.0-14-generic

lspci:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:9196]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
--
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [197b:0250] (rev 05)
Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:2500]
Kernel driver in use: jme
```

iwconfig:

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"peppermintpatty"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 98:FC:11:6C:E0:22   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
      Link Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1103   Missed beacon:0
```

lshw:

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:1c:7b:a1:95:04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.0.0-14-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 00:90:f5:c0:42:b3
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msix msi bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=jme driverversion=1.0.8 duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:56 memory:f7c20000-f7c23fff ioport:d100(size=128) ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7c10000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c00000-f7c0ffff
```

Any help would be appreciated. The last time I've dealt with wireless issues, the most given solution was NDIS wrapper and I seem sorely out-of-date.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/95360/how-to-get-a-stable-wlan-connection-with-a-lenovo-x121e for a similar description of the problem - this time the laptop is a Lenovo x121e. And http://askubuntu.com/questions/97308/ubuntu-11-10-wi-fi-connection-almost-stops-working-after-some-time, an Asus PCE-N15. It's always the RTL8188CE.

Comment: TRL8188CE support seems to be much better now with 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very much like [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/902557), flaky on Oneiric and almost never working on Precise.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having similar issues lately with a toshiba c655d-s5300.  I reverted to an older kernel at the grub menu, and now it is working.  Here's what IS working:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: e0:ca:94:5c:21:7a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.0.0-13-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11b
```

It WAS NOT working on the 3.0.0.14-generic kernel.