# RTL8188CE disconnects and won't reconnect on Lenovo E520

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless

I installed the RTL8188CE driver off the realtek website. It will connect after a fresh boot and work well. But at some point it disconnects (usually within 15 mins) and then will not reconnect. It remains stuck at "Obtaining IP address..." until it fails to connect entirely and will not connect without reboot.

dmesg output from disconnecting manually and trying to reconnect:

```
[  376.982528] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:18:e7:d1:13:a6 by local choice (reason=3)  
[  377.026775] cfg80211: All devices are disconnected, going to restore regulatory settings  
[  377.026788] cfg80211: Restoring regulatory settings  
[  377.026802] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain  
[  377.033575] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033585] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033592] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033597] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033602] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033608] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033613] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033619] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033623] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033629] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033634] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033639] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033644] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033650] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033654] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033660] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033665] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033670] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033675] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033680] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033685] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033691] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033696] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2467 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033701] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033706] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2472 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033712] cfg80211: 2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033717] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2484 MHz for a 20 MHz width   channel with regulatory rule:  
[  377.033722] cfg80211: 2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @  KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033730] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses   its own custom regulatory domain   
[  377.033736] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:  
[  377.033740] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain,   max_eirp)  
[  377.033746] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033751] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033757] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033762] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.033767] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)  
[  377.410687] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
[  381.585606] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
[  382.055261] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down  
[  382.056132] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready  
[  383.054538] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
[  385.443375] type=1400 audit(1326614570.735:25): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open"   parent=2934 profile="/sbin/dhclient" name="/var/lib/wicd/dhclient.conf" pid=2978   comm="dhclient" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0  
[  698.379232] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready  
[  698.462389] wlan0: authenticate with 00:18:e7:d1:13:a6 (try 1)  
[  698.464371] wlan0: authenticated  
[  698.464433] wlan0: associate with 00:18:e7:d1:13:a6 (try 1)  
[  698.467889] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:18:e7:d1:13:a6 (capab=0x421 status=0 aid=3)  
[  698.467899] wlan0: associated  
[  698.479224] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready  
[  698.889673] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down  
[  698.890592] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready  
[  708.491216] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Comment: You haven't provided any dmesg output or syslog output or /var/log/messages output. Is it absolutely necessary to use their driver? (I know nothing about that chipset.) Have you Googled and searched Launchpad? Sounds to me like you need to file a bug report.

Comment: the linux driver from realtek is supposed to work a lot better than the one provided in kernels from 3+. I had it working under 11.04 but after the upgrade to 11.10 things have gone downhill. I've reinstalled the propriety drivers but I've come up with this problem. - dmesg's added to original question

Comment: How so?  I recommend using the mainline driver unless you encounter actual problems.

A dmesg from manually disconnecting doesn't demonstrate the problem, does it?  :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [RealTek RTL8188CE WiFi adapter doesn't connect reliably](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90933/realtek-rtl8188ce-wifi-adapter-doesnt-connect-reliably)

Answer (score 2):

The way to FIX this is to recompile the kernel because of the update/upgrade it has not been picked up.

[Ubuntu Kernel Compile](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) read first

Choose your kernel below. Follow the instructions

Oneiric (11.10) Kernel 3.2 :

http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2012/01/13/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-ubuntu-11-10/

Oneiric (11.10) :

http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2011/10/28/how-to-compile-a-new-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-kernel/

*(this is not always the correct way but works)*