# I keep losing the Internet connection in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

I recently assembled a new desktop with an ASUS PCE-N15 wireless network adapter and my home wireless network is detected and I am able to connect to it and even access the Internet.

However, after little time I lose the Internet connection, not the wireless connection to the home network, and have to manually disconnect and reconnect in order to get Internet working.

Anyone has any ideas?

UPDATE: /var/log/messages

```
Apr 19 13:46:50 videl kernel: [13415.875472] rtl8192c: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.833899] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913925] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913926] cfg80211:     (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913927] cfg80211:     (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913929] cfg80211:     (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913930] cfg80211:     (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913932] cfg80211:     (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 19 13:58:08 videl kernel: [14093.913933] cfg80211:     (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Apr 19 13:58:13 videl kernel: [14098.456988] rtl8192c: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cfw.bin
```

UPDATE 2: The result of running `ip route list` with and without internet connection is the same:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlan0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.7  metric 2
```

Comment: `tail /var/log/messages`, please.

Comment: If you mean you can talk to other machines on the local network but not machines on the Internet, then perhaps it means the default route in the routing table is getting dropped.  When you next encounter the problem, run `ip route list` and paste the output in your question.

Comment: Could be an IP address conflict. Check your computers IP address against your routers DHCP table, and make sure that your computer name matches up. You could also try powering off the router for a bit to let it reassign ip addresses... 

Just a few thoughts.

Comment: I've checked, it is not an IP conflict :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same driver (rtl8192ce) as in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95360/how-to-get-a-stable-wlan-connection-with-a-lenovo-x121e) - and a very similar behaviour. Best solution up to now is to use kernel 3.0.0-14. It's not perfect but better than any of the later kernels.

Comment: I didn't try changing the kernel, but I looked at the post you mention and followed one of the answers that suggests running `watch sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` which does keep the Internet connection alive. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I was wrong, it took a few hours but the Internet connection eventually failed...

Comment: The problem seems to be gone, I've re-installed Ubuntu and kept kernel 3.0.0-12. Thanks.