# Newly installed Ubuntu on laptop, Wireless will not fuction

Tags: 12.04, wireless, laptop, toshiba

I am working on a new Toshiba Satellite c855d, and this morning it had windows 7 on it. Wireless was working.
When I booted Ubuntu, wireless was once again working.

I install 12.04 onto it, and now the wireless connection is no longer functioning. I'm not quite sure what to do, and I'm not terribly knowledgeable on the subject.

Thanks for any replies!

**Edit 1: Outputs for first commenter's requests**

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 00:26:6c:15:c8:4e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.0.130 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0104000-f0104fff memory:f0100000-f0103fff
```

and

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 14h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Device 9809
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Wrestler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6250/6310]
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson SD Flash Controller
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a0
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Device 43a1
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Hudson USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

does this help at all?

**Edit 2, installing the drivers:**

When I get to the point of compiling and installing the driver, I'm coming up with a lot of error messages. I will paste the output here:

```
norma@norma-Satellite-C855D:~$ cd rtl8192ce_*/
norma@norma-Satellite-C855D:~/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011$ make clean
gcc: error: /lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic-pae/build/include/linux/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/norma/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011/HAL/rtl8192'
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
rm -fr Modules.symvers
rm -fr Module.symvers
rm -fr Module.markers
rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr tags
make[2]: Entering directory `/'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/'
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/norma/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011/HAL/rtl8192'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
norma@norma-Satellite-C855D:~/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic-pae'
gcc: error: /lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic-pae/build/include/linux/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:49: *** CFLAGS was changed in "/home/norma/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011/HAL/rtl8192/Makefile". Fix it to use ccflags-y.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/norma/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011/HAL/rtl8192] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic-pae'
make: *** [all] Error 2
norma@norma-Satellite-C855D:~/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for norma: 
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic-pae'
gcc: error: /lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic-pae/build/include/linux/autoconf.h: No such
file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:49: *** CFLAGS was changed in "/home/norma/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011/HAL/rtl8192/Makefile". Fix it to use ccflags-y.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/norma/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011/HAL/rtl8192] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic-pae'
make: *** [all] Error 2
norma@norma-Satellite-C855D:~/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.2011$
```

Comment: We will need more information to assist you. Can you add the output from the command `sudo lshw -class network` and `lspci` to your question.

Comment: try `rfkill unblock all` , if that doesn't resolve issue post result of `rfkill list all` and `lsmod`

Comment: I searched a bit and found out there are many problem with realtech. This link found most promising - http://askubuntu.com/q/95360/35775 . If connected and internet is slow see this → http://askubuntu.com/q/205575/35775

Comment: The card is not claimed by any driver, so this version of Ubuntu does not support your card by default. Try to get a fixed internet connection, apply *all* updates and install `linux-firmware` and `linux-firmware-nonfree` packages, then reboot. If it still does not work, try installing a backported wireless kernel: `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-quantal-generic`, or even a complete newer backported kernel: `linux-generic-lts-quantal`.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This won't work on ubuntu 12.10

Go to Realtek’s website and look for your chipset.

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true

Download the appropriate driver for your WiFi card and unpack it to your home directory. You should now have a “rtl8192ce_*” folder in your home directory.
Get the tools necessary to compile the driver.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Now we need to unload and block the original kernel modules/drivers from the kernel. Otherwise they would destabilize the Realtek driver which we’re going to install:

```
sudo rmmod rtl8192ce
```

To blacklist the original kernel drivers/modules, open gedit:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Now insert the following two lines at the end of the file:

```
blacklist rtl8192ce
blacklist rtlwifi
```

Finally, it’s time to compile and install the official Realtek driver.

```
cd rtl8192ce_*/
make clean
make
sudo make install
exit
Reboot
```

To make sure you’re using the correct driver, run `lspci -v` and scroll down to your Realtek WiFi card. The line “Kernel driver in use” should read **“rtl8192CE”** (note the two capitals at the end), and you should have a new kernel module “r8192ce_pci” installed.