# realtek wireless not functioning on Toshiba after installing 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, realtek, toshiba

so like many users with a realtek wireless driver I've been having problems getting my wireless to work 
I'm on a Toshiba Satellite C875
My wifi adapter is RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n
and my kernal is 3.5.0-36-generic.

I managed to find a post on this site with almost my exact problem and a solution, [Newly installed Ubuntu on laptop, Wireless will not fuction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228517/newly-installed-ubuntu-on-laptop-wireless-will-not-fuction) , however, just like the poster I'm running into issues at the compiling phase. I've managed to work through a few issues that the poster had.

```
gcc: error: /lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic-pae/build/include/linux/autoconf.h: 
No such file or directory gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

This was caused because autoconf.h is now in a different folder (include/generated). I just had to make a copy of it in the include/linux folder and it got further. Same fix worked for modversions.h, which I found in the include/config folder.

after that though my problems with compiling look remarkably similar. Anyone have any suggestions on how to move forward from here.

This is the section of the solution where I'm having issues

```
cd rtl8192ce_*/
make clean
make
sudo make install
exit
Reboot
```

After I type in

```
make clean
```

I get this

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/aktd/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.20/HAL/rtl8192'
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions
rm -fr Modules.symvers
rm -fr Module.symvers
rm -fr Module.markers
rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr tags
make[2]: Entering directory `/'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/'
make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/aktd/rtl8192ce_linux_2.6.0006.0321.201/HAL/rtl8192'
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I feel like I'm so close here, but I just can't quite get it.

oh and I do have linux-headers-3.5.0-36-generic installed before anyone suggests fixing that, as I've seen that come up a lot as a possible solution on forums.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have build-essential installed? You may have better luck with the later version of the driver: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58267392/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0007.0809.2012.tar.gz