# Wi-Fi connection almost stops working after some time on an Asus PCE-N15

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RealTek RTL8188CE WiFi adapter doesn't connect reliably](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90933/realtek-rtl8188ce-wifi-adapter-doesnt-connect-reliably)

I have an **ASUS PCE-N15** in my PC, which I connect to my home network with `NetworkManager`. I use "WPA & WPA2 Personal" as a security method. The problem is that after some time Wi-Fi connection almost dies, stops working almost completely. Why I say *almost* is because some packets do flow from time to time, I can ping something (but with huge times like 1 second), but its exiguous, visiting sites doesn't not work. Nothing is written into syslog, `dmesg` shows nothing too.

There were several topics on this, including some solutions like changing `sysctl` variable or lowering security level, but it doesn't help.

Output from `sudo lshw -class network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: f4:6d:04:a2:61:06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.0.0-12-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febfc000-febfffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95360/how-to-get-a-stable-wlan-connection-with-a-lenovo-x121e) - it's the same WLAN adapter, Realtek's RTL 8188CE, and the same behaviour.